# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : NLog not writing to file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, nlog, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an issue with error logging in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC with NLog.

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project and experiencing issues with error logging using NLog. The problem is that the log file (`file1.txt`) is not being created.

Here is my code - `Program.cs`:

```cs
using System;
using NLog.Web;
using NLog;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Maxwell.Web.LeaseControl
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();

            try
            {
                logger.Debug("init main");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                LogManager.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                })
                .UseNLog();
    }
}
```

XML file (`NLog.config`):

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog-AspNetCore.txt">

    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
    </extensions>

    <targets>
        <variable name="logDirectory" value="logs/${shortdate}" />
        <target name="file1" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/file1.txt" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file1" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

`ProjectController.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using Maxwell.Web.LeaseControl.Interfaces;
using Maxwell.Web.LeaseControl.BLL;

namespace Projects
{
    [Area("Projects")]
    public class ProjectController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ProjectController> _logger;
        private IProject<ProjectBll> projectBll;

        public ProjectController(ILogger<ProjectController> logger, IProject<ProjectBll> projectBll)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this.projectBll = projectBll;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Hello, I got here 123 abs");
            try
            {
                return View("ProjectList");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred in the Index action.");
                return Json(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) and look for clues. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting